# Eclipse how to generate UML diagrams from code

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

Is there any Eclipse plugin capable of generating UML diagrams from Java code ?
I know about some of them but the point is that they all generate **Class Diagrams** from **Code**. The point is that I wanted to generate some other diagrams as well (for example: **DFD - Data Flow Diagram**)
If impossible just tell me about it - I will live with it...

Answer (score 3):

There are many plugins for that for that.
One plugin that I really like is ObjectAid:
http://www.objectaid.com/